# How to remove all entries except the last entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I can have the same entry matching different events.

[image]

In the example above I want to keep the 1800 row as its the latest time, so the last entry. The rest can be deleted. But I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm using the SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use formatted text for data, not images. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @DaleK apologies very new to SQL and the forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row AID, then you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by AID order by event desc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete res from 
( select t.*,row_number() over (partition by t.AID order by t.event desc) as seqNo
 from table t) res
where res.seqNo>1
```